# How to crop the rectangle effect in the appearance panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, appearance

How can I crop a dynamic rectangle effect so that the outsides of the rectangle don't show outside a certain fill?

please have a look of the appearance panel

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

The desired effect:

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

The reason not to use a clipping mask is to save the result as a graphic style to have the ability to apply it dynamically or through an action so I don't have to re-draw masks every time I use this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't** do it with one object and Appearance rectangles.

`Convert to Shape` effects in the **Appearance panel** remain at their shape. You can scale and move them, but you can't dynamically change their general shape - rectangle or ellipse (well, you can with other effects, but I'm unaware of a "shield shape" effect).

There's no way to "mask" or "trim" the `Convert to Shape` effects. You are asking for the impossible.

**Separate objects** rather than the Appearance Panel will work.

If you are *dead set* on using an Appearance stack, the **only** way I know to pull off what you want is via a **gradient fill** and gradient stops which line up.....

[image]

Gradient Stops in the same "location" create more of a solid line between the colors.